# How to resolve 'No protocol specified' for su user

Tags: ubuntu, gui, non-root-user

I am trying to use an alternate user (non-admin) to execute graphical software on my system. This alternate user has been named and given a UID and GID to match a remote system user of the same name. The UID is 500 so I believe that makes the user a 'non-login' user.

Starting from Ubuntu logged into my main account, I open a terminal and `su` to the alternate user. I then attempt to execute the command to start the application and receive 'No protocol specified'.

Is this because of the UID<1000, because of the `su` or because of the non-admin of the user?
How can I get this user to execute the application with a GUI?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The problem is *not* occurring because of the UID of the user. 500 is just fine as a UID, and that UID doesn't make it a 'non-login' user except in the eyes of the default settings of some few display managers.

The error message **No protocol specified** sounds like an application-specific error message, and an unhelpful one at that, but I am going to guess that the error is that the application is unable to contact your X11 display because it does not have permission to do so because it's running as a different user. Applications need a "magic cookie" (secret token) in order to talk to the X11 server so that other processes on the system running under other users cannot intrude on your display, create windows, and snoop your keystrokes. The other system user does not have access to this magic cookie because the permissions are set so that it is only accessible to the user who started the desktop environment (which is as it should be).

Try this, running as your original user, to copy the X11 cookie to the other account:

```
su - <otheruser> -c "unset XAUTHORITY; xauth add $(xauth list)"
```

then run your application. You may also need to unset `XAUTHORITY` in that shell too. That command extracts the magic cookie (`xauth list`) from your main user and adds it (`xauth add`) to where the other user can get it.

Comment: Bizarrely, using your quoted command gives 'su: must be run from a terminal'. But it *is* in a terminal...

Comment: @JCollins try `xauth list >/tmp/xa.$$; su - <otheruser> -c "unset XAUTHORITY; xargs xauth add </tmp/xa.$$"; rm -f /tmp/xa.$$` but be aware there's a horrible race condition in there.

Comment: @JCollins oops, yeah, that would be a problem if `su` wants to ask for a password. Try this new command.

Comment: @Celada, gold, worked a treat. Could you have a go at detailing what that command is doing and how? And maybe explaining why the original incarnation did not?

Comment: @JCollins I added some extra details for you.

Comment: @Celada thanks for that, great answer, now I'm wondering if that was intended to be a permanent solution or a per-session solution.

Comment: @JCollins you'll have to redo it each time after you log out and log in because a brand new magic cookie gets generated each time. That's normal, it's part of the security model.

Comment: The man page for `xauth` specifically identifies the "MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1" portion of the entries as the "protocolname".  I had no idea, until just now, but thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: This yields:  `xauth:  timeout in locking authority file /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority
Password: 
xauth: (argv):1:  bad "add" command line`

Answer (score 38):

In my case the new display server protocol `wayland` was the problem,

just do `xhost + local:` then other users (e.g. root) are allowed to run programs in your session, network connections however will not be allowed.

If you want to allow clients from **any host**, you can use `xhost +` without specifying any host at all. **This is however unsafe**, it would be better to just specify the host(s) for which you want to grant access to your session.

Comment: In my case `xhost +` was sufficient enough

Comment: @danger89 while this does work it allows any host to connect to your session if you have no firewall rules to prevent remote access (Not every distribution has firewall rules which deny all incoming requests e.g. ubuntu does not have preconfigured rules to prevent access to servers like samba or apache which the user might want to install) so for new linux users this could become a problem. Personally I would limit the access just to be on the save side

Comment: This worked for me... but the problem is, I already ran the program before as su. Why, all of a sudden it stopped working without this inconvenience?

Comment: Finally got around to updating to Wayland, thank you!

Comment: @MADforFUNandHappy however, that host would first have to connect via SSH or some similar means, i.e. it would still have to know the system password to use X services, right

Comment: So the xhost command should be done: just once (for the life of the computer), or once per session?

Comment: Holy frijoles, this actually worked for me! To be clear, within the ssh session where I was getting the error, I entered `xhost + local:` and tried again. It still gave me an error, but then the GUI app opened and ran.

Answer (score 13):

Suppose you want to brute force get yourself a connection with X...

Lets assume you are already running your commands on the server (where X runs), otherwise get that to work first and then use 'ssh -X user@server' from the client afterwards ;).

There might be several ways to run the xauth commands, for example, you might be using 'sudo', but that might lose or change environment variables. The following environment variables need to be preserved: DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY. To test if that is the case you could run 'echo $XAUTHORITY' in the same way you run your commands, but make sure you aren't expanding the environment variables before you run those commands. For example, try: sudo bash -c 'echo "$XAUTHORITY"' to see what XAUTHORITY really is after you run your sudo (if it disappears you might need to add something to your sudoers file, see elsewhere).

Eventually, run the following command as the user that you want to get access with, on the server:

`xauth info`

This will show the 'Authority file' that will be used (/root/.Xauthority by default, for root, or something like /home/theuser/.Xauthority). If it shows the correct .Xauthority file then you don't have to worry about the XAUTHORITY environment variable actually (actually, I wouldn't know when it wouldn't, except if you want to manipulate a non-standard place of that file).

Remove that file (if it even exists):

`mv /root/.Xauthority /root/.Xauthority.bak`

In the above command, replace `/root/.Xauthority` with the correct XAUTHORITY file for your case of course.

Recreate it, but empty (this is needed for a lot of commands):

`touch /root/.Xauthority`

At this point you'll get the **No protocol specified** error, even if you got **Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1** before. Find the authority file that the X server is using at the moment:

`ps aux | grep Xorg`

This should show something like:

`root      1153  0.0  1.0 149560 44464 tty7     Ss+  dec02   0:00 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -nolisten tcp -auth /var/run/sddm/{ef18c483-7891-4e82-80ef-2c8f9bd79711} -background none -noreset -displayfd 17 vt7`

The file name after `-auth` is what you need in the next command. Run this as root:

`sudo xauth -f '/var/run/sddm/{ef18c483-7891-4e82-80ef-2c8f9bd79711}' list`

That lists a 32 digit hexadecimal key. For example the output could be:

`hostname/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  c0eaf749aa252101a0f57d5087089db7`

Use that to generate your .Xauthority file (as user who needs to login again):

`xauth add $DISPLAY MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 c0eaf749aa252101a0f57d5087089db7`

replace 'c0eaf749aa252101a0f57d5087089db7' with what was returned by the list command for you. Now your .Xauthority should be size 51 bytes and you can connect to the X server (again).

PS If you start Xorg by running `/usr/bin/startx`, like me; then you might see something like:

```
root        1652  0.0  0.0  12788  5792 ?        Ss   jan20   0:00 login -- carlo
carlo       1834  0.0  0.0   8140  3468 tty1     Ss   jan20   0:00  \_ -bash
carlo       1887  0.0  0.0   7404  3236 tty1     S+   jan20   0:00      \_ /bin/sh /usr/bin/startx
carlo       1905  0.0  0.0   3912   828 tty1     S+   jan20   0:00          \_ xinit /home/carlo/.xinitrc -- /etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc :0 vt1 -keeptty -auth /tmp/serverauth.WWPpq4OSlA
root        1906  1.2  0.7 25576848 235104 tty1  Sl   jan20 207:56              \_ /usr/lib/Xorg -nolisten tcp :0 vt1 -keeptty -auth /tmp/serverauth.WWPpq4OSlA
carlo       1917  0.0  0.0 143408 10884 tty1     Sl   jan20   0:00              \_ startplasma-x11
```

And the `/tmp/serverauth.WWPpq4OSlA` was deleted.
See `/usr/bin/startx` script for how this works:

```
mcookie=`/usr/bin/mcookie`
xserverauthfile=`mktemp -p /tmp serverauth.XXXXXXXXXX`
trap "rm -f '$xserverauthfile'" HUP INT QUIT ILL TRAP KILL BUS TERM
xauth -q -f "$xserverauthfile" << EOF
add :$dummy . $mcookie
EOF
```

as well as

```
xauth -q << EOF
add $displayname . $mcookie
EOF
```

adding the random cookie to the users `.Xauthority` file.

In this case the cookie has completely vanished thus. The only place where you can get it back from is the memory (RAM) of the Xorg process; but I am too lazy to figure out how to recover that. Just restarting X should regenerate your `.Xauthority` file with a new cookie and also restart the server with that same cookie, of course.

Comment: There is no thread, this is a Q&A site, not a forum

Answer (score 4):

Try something like that

```
$ export LOGIN_USER="Math"
$ su - $LOGIN_USER
$ sudo xhost local:$LOGIN_USER &>/dev/null
```

[source](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/run-as-su-946986/#post4688176)

**Ps**: the accepted answer not worked for me

Answer (score 3):

Just type this in your terminal `xhost +SI:localuser:root` after that you type `export DISPLAY=:0.0` then try again

Comment: This ^ works but I have to run this command after evey reboot on Ubuntu 20. No big deal but a little bit to remember. Adding this line to my current user ~/.bashrc file fixes it for me:  ```export XAUTHORITY=~/.Xauthority``` The .Xauthority file sets the magic cookie params needed to open apps as root with xfce on Ubuntu 20.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error "No protocol specified" when I started an instance of Selenium 3.3.1 from an upstart script and then used the Chrome driver in Selenium. Selenium ran as the same user as X11, and DISPLAY shell environment variable was set correctly. What is interesting is that this error did not happen when I used the Firefox driver. Setting XAUTHORITY shell environment variable inside the upstart script to point to the value of $XAUTHORITY of the active X11 user fixed the error for the Chrome driver.

On a side note, the error "No protocol specified" was thoroughly buried by  Chrome/Chrome driver and was by no means easy to find. I noticed that Chrome kept creating directories in the pattern of `/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.*`, but they were quickly disappearing. I managed to notice that they contained a file `chrome_debug.log` which had a message "Cannot open display". I figured this was rather strange since I  have verified that the Selenium process had the correct DISPLAY in `/proc/$pid/environ` and examined the output of `strace` on the Selenium process more thoroughly, which revealed "No protocol specified" leading me eventually to this question.

This error can be reproduced by unsetting XAUTHORITY and trying to run some X11 client. For example:

```
$ XAUTHORITY= xeyes
No protocol specified
Error: Can't open display: :0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using clues in the accepted answers, I was able to solve the issue differently:

1. Locate the Xauth file in the account that works (Xauth1)
2. Locate the Xauth file in the account that doesn't (Xauth2)
3. Copy Xauth1 to Xauth2
4. Change the permissions of Xauth2

In code:

```
root@45c4933a8f1a:~# xauth info
Authority file:       /headless/.Xauthority
<snip>
root@45c4933a8f1a:~# su OtherUser
OtherUser@45c4933a8f1a:/headless$ xauth info
Authority file:       /home/OtherUser/.Xauthority
<snip>
OtherUser@45c4933a8f1a:/headless$ exit
exit
root@45c4933a8f1a:~# cp /headless/.Xauthority /home/OtherUser/.Xauthority 
root@45c4933a8f1a:~# chown OtherUser:OtherUser /home/OtherUser/.Xauthority
root@45c4933a8f1a:~# su OtherUser
```

Answer (score 1):

Let says you try to access to GUI as **user2** (*normal user*), then You need to load installation UI as **user2**.

Try to following this:

Login as **root**:

```
sudo su
```

Test the x server:

```
xclock
```

If you can see a clock running, that's good to go, now try run this:

```
xhost
```

The result should like this:

```
xhost SI:localuser:tri
# tri is my user name
```

Now let **user2** access xhost

```
xhost +SI:localuser:user2
```

now try to login again to **user2** and try to open any of GUI program.

Answer (score 0):

This was simple.
The problem happens when you are in root sate and want to use the **gksu** 
Just **exit**  the root state and try again

Answer (score 0):

To do all of this at once,

```
su -c 'cat $XAUTHORITY' $(logname) > ~/.Xauthority && XAUTHORITY=~/.Xauthority
```

Type in the login user's password when asked.

### Explanation

Building off tjb's answer, `xauth info` may not work (X11). When I tried this on the other user I received the error

```
xauth:  timeout in locking authority file /path/to/Xauthority
```

You may run `echo $XAUTHORITY` on user2 (one that doesn't work) to see user2's current authority file. User2 may not have proper access to this file so you can change it to something else (Ex: /home/user2/.Xauthority) or edit the files permissions.
Changing the file as to not risk security issues:

```
XAUTHORITY=/home/user2/.Xauthority
```

and then follow the rest of tjb's answer.