# x11 application not work after su

Tags: centos, x11

On a terminal (local terminal or ssh with X11 forwarding), a user can open X application however, another user is not able after `su`ing.

Please see the output below.

```
u1@cluster:~$ xclock
u1@cluster:~$ su
Password:
root@cluster:# su - u2
[u2@cluster ~]$ xclock
No protocol specified
Error: Can't open display: localhost:11.0
[u2@cluster ~]$
```

So, what is the solution?

Comment: [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209746/how-to-resolve-no-protocol-specified-for-su-user) may help.

Answer (score 0):

I usually create the following script in either `/usr/local/bin` or `$HOME/bin`.

```
#!/bin/bash
HOSTNAME=`uname -n`
ARG=`echo $DISPLAY | sed -e "s/localhost/$HOSTNAME\/unix/"`
XAUTH=`/usr/bin/xauth -i -f ~/.Xauthority list ${ARG}`

echo "The following is used for graphical displays through ssh."
echo "Copy and paste the following commands AFTER you have \"su - [user]\""
echo "----------------  Copy below  ------------------------------------"
echo "DISPLAY=$DISPLAY;export DISPLAY"
echo "/usr/bin/xauth -bi add \\"
echo "${XAUTH}"
echo "----------------  Copy above  ------------------------------------"
```

You would execute this script **before** using `su` or `sudo`. After becoming the other user, cut and paste the output as noted. Your `X` programs should run.

```
[bschuck@dhcp-10-100-11-138 ~]$ bin/xtunnel 
The following is used for graphical displays through ssh.
Copy and paste the following commands AFTER you have "su - [user]"
----------------  Copy below  ------------------------------------
DISPLAY=localhost:10.0;export DISPLAY
/usr/bin/xauth -bi add \
dhcp-10-100-11-138/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 \
b64ace6b49bb1b49c59679a2db6411eb
----------------  Copy above  ------------------------------------
[bschuck@dhcp-10-100-11-138 ~]$ su - zippy
Password: 
[zippy@dhcp-10-100-11-138 ~]$ DISPLAY=localhost:10.0;export DISPLAY
[zippy@dhcp-10-100-11-138 ~]$ /usr/bin/xauth -bi add \
> dhcp-10-100-11-138/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  
b64ace6b49bb1b49c59679a2db6411eb
[zippy@dhcp-10-100-11-138 ~]$ xclock &
[1] 6076
[zippy@dhcp-10-100-11-138 ~]$
```